# What generates the "text file busy" message in Unix?

Tags: unix

What operation generates the error "text file busy"? I am unable to tell exactly.

I think it is related to the fact that I'm creating a temporary python script (using tempfile) and using execl from it, but I think that execl changes the file being run.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

This error means you are trying to modify an executable while it is executing. The "Text" here refers to the fact that the file being modified is the text segment for a running program. Use `lsof` to check what other processes are using it. You can use `kill` command to kill it if needed.

Comment: The `Text file busy` error in specific is about trying to modify an executable while it is executing. The "Text" here refers to the fact that the file being modified is the [text segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) for a running program. This is a very special case, and not the generic one that your answer seems to suggest. Even so, your answer isn't entirely incorrect.

Comment: The answer with the comment seems complete.

Comment: The OP asked which operation generates the error, not for an explnation of what the error means.

Comment: I think the fact that unix assumes files are "text files" is ilogical, in my case it was a binary file which prompted this error.

Comment: @FelipeValdes The name is historical from the terminology of a half century ago.  For example, in multics the text segment of a program was distinct from the link segment, and even earlier people talked about binary text.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1282540/833300

Comment: @FelipeValdes Note also that unix historically distinguishes between the code segment or text segment, which is read-only, and the data segment, which is read-write.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment#Text

Comment: @jma Thank you for your clarification, I was not aware of this. given it's 2018, perhaps it's time to change the error message a bit?

Comment: What is "lsof"? I get command not found. Is there a way to do this that is just part of the operating system, that does not require installing extra tools?

Comment: This worked the first time, but the command returns nothing now, even though it says the file is busy

Comment: just to share my n=1 experience: for me it happened when MountainDuck was still syncing some files and I was already trying to execute them from another ssh connection. So be mindful of background syncing apps when you're sure no other process should be accessing your file but you.

Answer (score 34):

It's a while since I've seen that message, but it used to be prevalent in System V R3 or thereabouts a good couple of decades ago.  Back then, it meant that you could not change a program executable while it was running.

For example, I was building a `make` workalike called `rmk`, and after a while it was self-maintaining.  I would run the development version and have it build a new version.  To get it to work, it was necessary to use the workaround:

```
gcc -g -Wall -o rmk1 main.o -L. -lrmk -L/Users/jleffler/lib/64 -ljl
if [ -f rmk ] ; then mv rmk rmk2 ; else true; fi ; mv rmk1 rmk
```

So, to avoid problems with the 'text file busy', the build created a new file `rmk1`, then moved the old `rmk` to `rmk2` (rename wasn't a problem; unlink was), and then moved the newly built `rmk1` to `rmk`.

I haven't seen the error on a modern system in quite a while...but I don't all that often have programs rebuilding themselves.

Comment: Here's a super quick reproducer: `echo -e '#include <unistd.h>\nint main(void){sleep (5);return 0;}' > slowprog.c && cc slowprog.c && cp a.out b.out && (./a.out &) ; sleep 1 && cp b.out a.out`. Produced the error message "cp: cannot create regular file ‘a.out’: Text file busy" on my newish Fedora.

Comment: @ArjunShankar here is a C reproduction on a modern Linux with "direct" system calls: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764946/what-generates-the-text-file-busy-message-in-unix/52427512#52427512 GCC can only overwrite running executables nowadays because if first does an `unlink` by default.

Answer (score 28):

> This occurs when you try and write to a file that is currently being executed by the kernel, or execute a file that is currently open for writing.

Source: http://wiki.wlug.org.nz/ETXTBSY

Answer (score 18):

**Minimal runnable C POSIX reproduction example**

I recommend understanding the underlying API to better see what is going on.

sleep.c

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    sleep(10000);
}
```

busy.c

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    int ret = open("sleep.out", O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC);
    assert(errno == ETXTBSY);
    perror("");
    assert(ret == -1);
}
```

Compile and run:

```
gcc -std=c99 -o sleep.out ./sleep.c
gcc -std=c99 -o busy.out ./busy.c
./sleep.out &
./busy.out
```

`busy.out` passes the asserts, and `perror` outputs:

```
Text file busy
```

so we deduce that the message is hardcoded in glibc itself.

Alternatively:

```
echo asdf > sleep.out
```

makes Bash output:

```
-bash: sleep.out: Text file busy
```

For a more complex application, you can also observe it with `strace`:

```
strace ./busy.out
```

which contains:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "sleep.out", O_WRONLY) = -1 ETXTBSY (Text file busy)
```

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04, Linux kernel 4.15.0.

**The error does not happen if you `unlink` first**

notbusy.c

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    assert(unlink("sleep.out") == 0);
    assert(open("sleep.out", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT) != -1);
}
```

Then compile and run analogously to the above, and those asserts pass.

This explains why it works for certain programs but not others. E.g. if you do:

```
gcc -std=c99 -o sleep.out ./sleep.c
./sleep.out &
gcc -std=c99 -o sleep.out ./sleep.c
```

that does not generate an error, even though the second `gcc` call is writing to `sleep.out`.

A quick `strace` shows that GCC first unlinks before writing:

```
 strace -f gcc -std=c99 -o sleep.out ./sleep.c |& grep sleep.out
```

contains:

```
[pid  3992] unlink("sleep.out")         = 0
[pid  3992] openat(AT_FDCWD, "sleep.out", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
```

The reason it does not fail is that when you `unlink` and re-write the file, it creates a new inode, and keeps a temporary dangling inode for the running executable file.

But if you just `write` without `unlink`, then it tries to write to the same protected inode as the running executable.

**POSIX 7 `open()`**

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html

> [ETXTBSY]
>
> The file is a pure procedure (shared text) file that is being executed and oflag is O_WRONLY or O_RDWR.

**man 2 open**

> ETXTBSY
>
> pathname refers to an executable image which is currently being executed and write access was requested.

**glibc source**

A quick grep on 2.30 gives:

```
sysdeps/gnu/errlist.c:299:    [ERR_REMAP (ETXTBSY)] = N_("Text file busy"),
sysdeps/mach/hurd/bits/errno.h:62:  ETXTBSY                        = 0x4000001a,        /* Text file busy */
```

and a manual hit in `manual/errno.texi`:

```
@deftypevr Macro int ETXTBSY
@standards{BSD, errno.h}
@errno{ETXTBSY, 26, Text file busy}
An attempt to execute a file that is currently open for writing, or
write to a file that is currently being executed.  Often using a
debugger to run a program is considered having it open for writing and
will cause this error.  (The name stands for ``text file busy''.)  This
is not an error on @gnuhurdsystems{}; the text is copied as necessary.
@end deftypevr
```

Comment: The rationale for the unlink case is that the file is no longer accessible from that directory, but the inode is still there with a refcount > 0. If you re-use the name, it's then a new file in a new inode - whereas if you don't unlink first, you're actually trying to write to the protected inode.

Comment: @Penz obrigado for the comment, Leandro. I also wonder why, conversely, does it give an error if you try to write without `unlink`. Does Linux ever read the file more than once after the first `exec` call?

Comment: What's generating the ETXTBSY is the inode protection. Without unlink, any writes go to the inode that's protected by the file execution; with unlink, you get a new inode that is not protected. (not sure "protected" is the term here, but that's the idea)

Comment: fwiw fopen(argv[0]...) will also create the error ^^

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I was trying to execute a shell file (with an extension .sh)
in a csh environment, and I was getting that error message.

just running with bash it worked for me.
For example

> bash file.sh

Comment: Did it have a `#!/bin/bash` header?

Comment: It has the following header

#!/bin/sh

Comment: You might want to try using `#!/usr/bin/csh` or equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

You may find this to be more common on CIFS/SMB network shares. Windows doesn't allow for a file to be written when something else has that file open, and even if the service is not Windows (it might be some other NAS product), it will likely reproduce the same behaviour. Potentially, it might also be a manifestation of some underlying NAS issue vaguely related to locking/replication.

Answer (score 3):

If trying to build `phpredis` on a Linux box you might need to give it time to complete modifying the file permissions, with a `sleep` command, before running the file:

```
chmod a+x /usr/bin/php/scripts/phpize \
  && sleep 1 \
  && /usr/bin/php/scripts/phpize
```

Comment: I don't think `chmod` would return before the permissions were set. That might be a filesystem issue.

Comment: This occured inside a Docker image being built.

Comment: Docker has multiple storage drivers, I guess not all of them are perfect.

Comment: Still, it's a very good hint for people experiencing this issue when building docker image.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running the .sh from a ssh connection with a tool like MobaXTerm, and if said tool has an autosave utility to edit remote file from local machine, that will lock the file.

Closing and reopening the SSH session solves it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know the cause but I can contribute a quick and easy work around.

I just experienced this this oddity on CentOS 6 after `cat > shScript.sh` (paste, `^Z`) then editing the file in KWrite. Oddly there was no discernible instance (`ps -ef`) of the script executing.

My quick work around was simply to `cp shScript.sh shScript2.sh` then I was able to execute `shScript2.sh`. Then I deleted both. Done!

Comment: Your problem was because you *suspended* the `cat` process. Next time use ^D, not ^Z.

Comment: Quite right Vladimir. Thanks! That's what I'd have done in DOS/CMD prompt. Old habbits... hasn't happened since :)

Comment: I faced the same issue, worked with the copy method, thanks

Answer (score 1):

One of my experience:

I always change the default keyboard shortcut of Chrome through reverse engineering. After modification, I forgot to close Chrome and ran the following:

```
sudo cp chrome /opt/google/chrome/chrome
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/google/chrome/chrome': Text file busy
```

Using strace, you can find the more details:

```
sudo strace cp ./chrome /opt/google/chrome/chrome 2>&1 |grep 'Text file busy'
open("/opt/google/chrome/chrome", O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC) = -1 ETXTBSY (Text file busy)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have come across into this error while copying a certain amount of files from a remote server into a shared folder via `rsync`.

In my case, the shared folder triggered the error.

I was trying to copy the files with a bash script running inside a Ubuntu VM hosted by Virtualbox on a Windows OS.

I solved the problem by copying these files into a standard folder via `rsync` and then moving them into the shared folder via `cp` / `mv`.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this in PHP when using `fopen()` on a file and then trying to `unlink()` it before using `fclose()` on it.

No good:

```php
$handle = fopen('file.txt');
// do something
unlink('file.txt');
```

Good:

```php
$handle = fopen('file.txt');
// do something
fclose($handle);
unlink('file.txt');
```

Comment: On windows I guess? On linux the system usually allows us to delete open files - the reference in the directory is eliminated, but the data (inode) is fred only when the number of references reaches 0.

Comment: No, this was on Centos.

Comment: Tested it on Linux 4.7.10 with ext4 filesystem and it haven't produced any error, worked as Penz mentioned. File deleted successfully. Maybe dtbarne is using some special filesystem.

Comment: Was running this on vagrant - might be due to it being a shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
root@h1:bin[0]# mount h2:/ /x             
root@h1:bin[0]# cp /usr/bin/cat /x/usr/local/bin/
root@h1:bin[0]# umount /x
...
root@h2:~[0]# /usr/local/bin/cat 
-bash: /usr/local/bin/cat: Text file busy
root@h2:~[126]#

ubuntu 20.04, 5.4.0-40-generic
nfsd problem, after reboot ok
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: alternatively ```/usr/bin/dd of=/usr/bin/dd``` outputs ```/usr/bin/dd: failed to open '/usr/bin/dd': Text file busy```

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when a script file is executed that uses a `#!/usr/bin/env` shebang line, omitting an actual environment (e.g. `bash`).

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem when I called a `executable file` which is being transfered and not complete.

when the transfer complete, I successfully called that command.