# Cannot write file from cronjob

Tags: c, cron, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a small Raspberry PI cluster where each of the individual PIs get program updates from a mothership. Everything is on a local LAN with no exposure to the internet.

The code to update the executable file is:

```
strcpy(tmp,"/home/sw/update");
f = fopen(tmp, "w");
if (f == NULL)  { 
        printf("Could not open program %s to update\n",tmp);
        return 1;
} 
fwrite(cmd,sizeof(char),totalRead-2,f);
fclose(f);
```

If I run it from the shell (as root) it works fine. Running it as a cron job always fails with the above message "Could not open program...."

I have set the permissions to 777 and the owner of the file to be updated to root (to eliminate those issues). The update program is run on each PI in the cluster once an hour (there is another method to determine if the update is required). The cron table entry is:

```
0 * * * * /home/sw/updatepi >> /var/log/updatepi.log
```

Any ideas?

Comment: check for errno and tell us its value

Comment: @robin.koch errno=26

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764946/what-generates-the-text-file-busy-message-in-unix

Comment: Text file busy. I've checked, the executable is not in memory. What other things would cause it to be marked in use?

Comment: Sorry. Your last comment got in before mine. I think I figured it out. There's a race condition and the update program was losing.