# Request user input in Linux via script and create a file according to user input

Tags: linux

I am trying to create a script in Linux that will prompt the user to input the name of a file and according to the user's input it will create the file and put the following in the file "This is a file (filename)."

This is my attempt so far.

```
cat > hw5_script
echo "Enter filename:"
read filename
echo "This is a file filename"
```

This doesn't work for me. Just wondering what I am doing wrong? Any suggestions or input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The script will stop when it executes the line `cat > hw5_script`. It will wait for the user to enter something followed by EOF, and write all that into the file `hw5_script`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not redirecting the output of the script to the file, and you're not using `$` to expand the variable. Change the last line of the script to:

```
echo "This is a file $filename" > "$filename"
```

Comment: It's still not working. I am getting an error message that says text file busy when I try to run the script. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764946/what-generates-the-text-file-busy-message-in-unix

Comment: So this should work cat > hw5_script echo "Enter filename:" read filename echo "This is a file $filename" > "$filename"?

Comment: That's what I wrote in my answer. The only change you need to make is to the last `echo` line. This is very basic shell scripting.

Comment: Yes I know but I am a newbie. It's still not working. I'm still getting the same error message, but thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you read the other question. You need to find the other process that has your script file open and get it to close the file.