# Writing in the executable while running the program

Tags: c, linux, file, byte

I'm writing a C program and I would like to be able to store data inside the executable file.
I tried making a function to write a single byte at the end of the file but it looks like it can't open the file because it reaches the printf and then gives "segmentation fault".

```
void writeByte(char c){

    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("game","wb");

    if(f == 0)
        printf("\nFile not found\n");

    fseek(f,-1,SEEK_END);
    fwrite(&c,1,sizeof(char),f);

    fclose(f);

}
```

The file is in the correct directory and the name is correct. When I try to read the last byte instead of writing it works without problems.

Edit: I know I should abort the program instead of trying to write anyway but my main problem is that the program can't open the file despite being in the same directory.

Comment: You should abort the program rather than trying to access the file, if you found that the file could not be opened.

Comment: I think we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: What is the __exact__ output of your program when you try to write?

Comment: You should better present the output you want to get, in order for others to understand it better and help you!

Comment: Also what file you need to open? Is it text file or something else? Maybe you need to add .txt or whatever it is. https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen

Comment: I'm trying to open the executable of the program itself

Comment: So, you maybe should use: .exe after the name of the file?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a [mre]. I suggest to add comments how you modify the program to make it read from the file instead of writing to it. Maybe you should add `perror("fopen")` or similar to the error handling of `fopen`. The error return value does not necessarily mean "file not found". There are other possible errors. Do you use a real Linux system or WSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several unrelated problems in your code and the problem you're trying to solve.

**First** you lack proper error handling. If any function that can fail (like e.g. `fopen`) fails, you should act accordingly. If, for example you did

```
#include <error.h>
#include <errno.h>
...
f = fopen("game","wb");
if ( f == NULL ) {
    error(1,errno,"File could not be opened");
}
...
```

You would have recieved an useful error message like

```
./game: File could not be opened: Text file busy
```

You printed a message, which is not even correct (the file not beeing able to be opened is somthing different, than not beeing found) and continued the program which resulted in a segmentation fault because you dereferenced the `NULL` pointer stored in `f` after the failure of `fopen`.

**Second** As the message tells us (at least on my linux machine), the file is busy. That means, that my operating system does not allow me to open the executable I'm running in write mode. The answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764946/what-generates-the-text-file-busy-message-in-unix) question lists numerous source of the explanation of this error message. There might be ways to get around this and open a running executable in write mode, but I doubt this is easy and I doubt that this would solve your problem because:...

**Third** Executable files are stored in a special binary format (usually ELF on Linux). They are not designed to be manually modified. I don't know what happens if you just append data to it, but you could run into serious problems if your not very careful and know what you're doing.

If you just try to store data, use another plain and fresh file. If you're hoping to append code to an executable, you really should gather some background information about ELF files (e.g. from `man elf`) before continuing.