# Cannot lock a specific file type in C

Tags: c, locking, fcntl

I am new to C and programming in general. I have created a program where it will try to lock the file I input on the terminal and I want to lock the GCC compiled file, "lockDemo", but it does not work because whenever I open another terminal to lock the file, the process does not get blocked.

`gcc-o lockDemo lockdemo.c`

However, if I try to lock the uncompiled C file, "lockdemo.c", it works as intended. e.g, if I lock the lockdemo.c file in the first terminal and I try to lock it again in a second terminal, the process is blocked until the lock is released in the first terminal.

Why can't I lock the compiled file?

my code

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* file = argv[1];
    int fd;
    struct flock lock;

    //Open file descriptor
    fd = open (file, O_WRONLY);
        
    printf ("Press <ENTER> to lock\n");
    getchar();

    printf("Trying to get lock...");
    //Initialize lock struct
    memset (&lock, 0, sizeof(lock));
    lock.l_type = F_WRLCK;
    //Set a lock to the file
    fcntl (fd, F_SETLKW, &lock);
    printf("got lock\n");

    printf ("Press <ENTER> to release lock\n");
    getchar ();

    
    //Relase lock
    lock.l_type = F_UNLCK;
    fcntl (fd, F_SETLKW, &lock);
    printf ("Unlocked\n");

    close (fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should check that `open()` succeeded.

Comment: Your code is very similar to that of [this example](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=23618&seqNum=4).   It looks as if you are doing things right, except in reinforcement of what Barmer suggests, you should always check the return values of functions that return them.   Here it is especially important as there are many reasons a function could fail, making the following steps  in this code to domino.  File permissions comes to mind.

Comment: So I tried checking if the return value is -1, and used perror to check. It says "Text file busy". I tried to search on how to fix this and saw this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764946/what-generates-the-text-file-busy-message-in-unix

the solution recommends to find the process by issuing "lsof" and "kill" it, however, I am not sure how to find the process